# Map Vuex getter to a computed property AFTER component is created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Is it even possible?

I know I can do it like this:

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            xyz: 'xyz'
        }),
```

but I was wondering if I can do it using inherited mapGetters, i.e. in `created` hook:

```
created () {
        this.$options.computed = Object.assign(this.$options.computed, {...this.dependencies.mapGetters(this.stores)});

        console.log(this.$options.computed); // returns mapped getters
    },
```

Console output returns mapped getters, but it doesn't seem to work, in Vue DevTools those Vuex bindings are undefined.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have component xyz and A, B, C components are extending xyz. I'd rather import `mapGetters` in xyz, than in each A, B, C.

Comment: "Extending" using `Vue.extend()`?

Comment: @acdcjunior yes

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. There's no way around.

Also,

> The [$options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) is read only.

Comment: `$options` is not read only, where did you find it? Just in this code sample I'm changing it and there is no warning or error. It's also possible to edit `$options.components` to register components from extended component.

Comment: you might not get error, use 'strict' mode and then you'll find the error using it.